# How I can add an host via jboss-cli

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

How I can add a new host entry using jboss-cli to a Wildfly 12 instalation?

I tried this command:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=127.0.0.10:add
```

But I got this error:

```
failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYUT0087: Duplicate default 
web module 'ROOT.war' configured on server 'default-server', host '127.0.0.10'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename the `default-web-module` during the add. For example:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=127.0.0.10:add(default-web-module="default.war")
```